# HTML li ul dropdown menu hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a dropdown menu and i'm trying to display it's submenus using jquery.
So far i have managed to display the sub menu, but only by ID name.

How do you display only the submenu for the li item that is clicked?
I tried:
   $(this).children("ul)".addclass("expand").show();
but no go.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/menu.js"></script></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="includes/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="z-index:100;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left: 0;min-width:1000px;">
        <div id="menuJQ">
            <ul class="menuJQ">
                <li><span style="padding-top:9px;padding-left:5px;"><img src='includes/css/images/bblogo.png' onClick="window.location = 'index.php';">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="parent" href="#"><span>Product View</span></a>    
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Request Tool</span></a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search</span></a>
                    <div>
                        <ul id="sub1">
                            <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Integrity Query</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Internal DevTasks</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>3Results</span></a>
                                <div>
                                    <ul id="sub2">
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="3"><span>Issues for Stability Team</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.parent').click(function() {
        $("#sub1").addClass("expand").toggle("fast");
        var submenu_active = false;
    });

    var submenu_active = false;
     $('div#menuJQ ul ul').mouseenter(function() {
        submenu_active = true;      
     });

    $('div#menuJQ ul ul').mouseleave(function() {
        submenu_active = false;
        setTimeout(function() { 
            if (submenu_active === false) $('div#menuJQ ul ul').hide("fast");});
    });
});
```

Comment: Got it!

$(this).next("ul").addClass("expand").toggle("fast");

But i had to remove the "<div></div>" from around the sub menu.
Now my menus are misaligned, but the click functionality works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/sefbT/

You have to put script in `head` or `body` not outside of `html`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menuJQ > ul li').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('ul:first', this).show();
    });
});
```

### css:

```
ul ul {
    display:none;
}
```

### and this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#menuJQ > ul li').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('ul:first', this).show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="z-index:100;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left: 0;min-width:1000px;">
        <div id="menuJQ">
            <ul class="menuJQ">
                <li>123</li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a class="parent" href="#"><span>Product View</span></a> 
                    <div>
                        <ul style='padding:0 0 0 50px;'>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Request Tool</span></a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>Search</span></a>

                    <div>
                        <ul id="sub1" style='padding:0 0 0 50px;'>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>DevTask Search</span></a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Active Machines</span></a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Integrity Query</span></a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><span>Internal DevTasks</span></a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="parent"><span>3Results</span></a>

                                <div>
                                    <ul id="sub2" style='padding:0 0 0 50px;'>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#" target='_blank'><span>Latest Smoke Results</span></a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="3"><span>Issues for Stability Team</span></a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jai...THanks! My jquery was actually in a separate js file. Everything works now, except some alignment issues, and i noticed that when in move from sbumenu1 to submenu2, then try to go back to submenu1...both menus disppear.